# How would I go about turning this code into so I give the parameters to the method by hand and it returns a 2D char array back?

Tags: java, arrays, char

```java
public static void tehtava7() {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Give height");
    int height = input.nextInt();

    char[][] array = new char[height][height];

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
            if (row == col || col == 0 || col == height - 1) {
                array[row][col] = 'X';
            } else {
                array[row][col] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    printTwoDimCharArray(array);
}

public static void printTwoDimCharArray(char[][] myarray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myarray[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(myarray[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    tehtava7();
}
```

I need to give the parameter to the method by hand and return a 2D char array depending on the `height * height` I give to the method. It should also print the same `N` shape depending on the parameter given. How would I go about doing this? So basically I would not ask the user the height but import it manually.

Comment: When you say *"give the parameter to the method by hand"* I think you mean read it from the user, but then you say *"i would not ask the user the height but import it manually."* which just got me confused. Could you clarify? Also what do you mean with *"print the same N shape"* You need to make an "N" shape?

Comment: Sorry i'm trying my best to translate the question from finnish to english but i need to give the height values to the tehtava7(); method myself without the "Give height?" question if that makes any sense. And yes it needs to print the letter N with "X" and " " (spaces).

Comment: So, the user has to type the values and you'll return a 2D char array where you'll print a diagonal of `X`, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. And the values are typed into  public static void main(String[] args) {
        tehtava7();

Answer (score 1):

> i would not ask the user the `height` but import it manually.

First, I recommend that you treat `height` as a parameter to your function.

BEFORE:

```java
    public static void tehtava7() {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Give height");
        int height = input.nextInt();

        char [][] array = new char[height][height];
        // ...
```

AFTER:

```java
    public static void tehtava7(int height) {
        //                      ^--- NOTICE: NEW PARAMETER

        char [][] array = new char[height][height];
        // ...
```

Next, determine how you would like to "import" this.

Import by using an array of heights:

BEFORE:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tehtava7();
    }
```

AFTER:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] heights = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 }; // heights to import
        for(int height : heights) {
            tehtava7(height);
            //       ^---- NOTICE: LOOP AGAINST PARAMETERS
        }
    }
```

... or import parameters directly from command line:

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // args = command line options

        // loop over command line options, convert to integer
        int[] heights = new int[args.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            heights[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }

        for(int height : heights) {
            tehtava7(height);
            //       ^---- NOTICE: LOOP AGAINST PARAMETERS
        }
    }
```

```sh
java MyClass 2 4 6 8
```

output:

```
XX
XX
X  X
XX X
X XX
X  X
X    X
XX   X
X X  X
X  X X
X   XX
X    X
X      X
XX     X
X X    X
X  X   X
X   X  X
X    X X
X     XX
X      X
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your program is working correctly but you want to separate the logic of reading the height from the user from the method `tehtava7()`

So, basically you need to move that logic to the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Write the height: ");
    int height = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Then you can use that height to pass it as a parameter to `tehtava7(...)`, so your method signature would become:

```
public static void tehtava7(int height) {
    // Your code here
}
```

But now, you want to return the 2D `char` array from it, so we need to change `void` for `char[][]` and add a `return` at the end, so in the end `tehtava7` would end up as:

```
public static char[][] tehtava7(int height) {
    char[][] array = new char[height][height];

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
            if (row == col || col == 0 || col == height - 1) {
                array[row][col] = 'X';
            } else {
                array[row][col] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

And now you can use it on the `main` method like this:

```
tehtava7(height);
```

But as it returns a `char[][]` and you still need to print the `N` pattern you can do it this way:

```
printTwoDimCharArray(tehtava7(height));
```

And in the end, your whole program would look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PatternSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Write the height: ");
        int height = scanner.nextInt();
        /*
        Or you could make the call to tehtava7 and store it 
        in a 2D char array, and then use that as a parameter 
        for the print method like this:
        char[][] tehtavaArray = tehtava7(height);
        printTwoDimCharArray(tehtavaArray);
        */
        printTwoDimCharArray(tehtava7(height));
    }

    private static char[][] tehtava7(int height) {
        char[][] array = new char[height][height];

        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
                if (row == col || col == 0 || col == height - 1) {
                    array[row][col] = 'X';
                } else {
                    array[row][col] = ' ';
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static void printTwoDimCharArray(char[][] myarray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myarray[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(myarray[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
Write the height: 7
X     X
XX    X
X X   X
X  X  X
X   X X
X    XX
X     X
```

I must say, congratulations, you were almost there, keep the good work :)

Comment: If any of the answers, solved your question be sure to mark it as accepted, this let other know that your question got solved